# how to use CASE condition with database datas

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use `CASE CONDITION` with the datas from my `database` but it's not working

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN `vessel_name` == 'SAMMY' AND `vessel_status` == 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP'
      THEN 'asdf' 
  END 
FROM `pending_list`
```

I'm trying to `echo` out `AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP` if the statement is `TRUE`

here is my `database`:
column name `vessel_name` row value `SAMMY`
column name `vessel_status` row value `AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP`

if the condition is true, EXAMPLE RESULT MUST BE:

```
Vessel Name:  SAMMY              
Vessel Status:  AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP
```

if the condition is false, EXAMPLE RESULT MUST BE:

```
Vessel Name:  SAMMY              
Vessel Status:  NO AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP
```

Here is my whole code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" data-toggle="table" id="resultTable">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th data-sortable="true">Vessel Name</th>
                <th data-sortable="true">Vessel Status</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SAMMY</th>
                <th><?php "SELECT CASE WHEN `vessel_status` = 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' 
            THEN 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' 
            ELSE 'NO AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' 
       END as `vessel_status`
FROM `pending_list`
WHERE `vessel_name` = 'SAMMY'"  ?></th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: is my syntax is correct?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `asdf` will be echo out @juergend

Comment: It is correct when you use a single `=` instead of `==`

Comment: but there is no output

Comment: Well then add example data to your question.

Comment: i edited my post. can you check it again? thank you

Comment: I added an answer. But your question is still not that clear since you only provided expected output and no example data

Comment: sorry i still don't get it. still no output even the `ELSE` is not working

Comment: i added my code for the table

Comment: Well the query won't execute for itself. Please take a PHP/SQL tutorial. You need to run the query and handle the result of it in PHP

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if u provide some sample data. Basis my assumption I have given my opinion. Please check ...

You can write sql like below

```
"SELECT vessel_name, CASE WHEN `vessel_status` = 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' THEN 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' ELSE 'NO AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' END as vessel_status 
FROM `pending_list`"
```

Also in the html part mysql connection and query execution method must be called to fetch the data. Right now it is not clear how many data from the table would be fetched by this query. If more than 1 records are being fetched u have to loop thru it else just show data as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT vessel_name, CASE WHEN `vessel_status` = 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' THEN 'AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' ELSE 'NO AVAILABLE PROPOSE LINEUP' END as vessel_status 
FROM `pending_list`";

$conn = mysql_connect('host','username','password') or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db(db_name);
$recordset = mysql_query($sql ,$conn) or die(mysql_error);
```

if only one record is coming then

```
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($recordset);
$vessel_status = $obj->vessel_status ;
$vessel_name = $obj->vessel_name ;
```

if more than one records are cming then loop thru it

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($recordset))
{
    $vessel_status = $obj->vessel_status ;
    $vessel_name = $obj->vessel_name ;
}


mysql_free_result($recordset);
```